# spring mvc:resources - are files cached locally?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching

I'm using mvc:resources in Spring to serve static content.  I'm uploading files to the location directory via an html form in Spring.  But it seems like Spring still returns 404 for a few seconds after it's uploaded.

I'm using Spring mvc 4.1.4.

This is an issue because the view I'm forwarding to attempts to display the image.

I checked via Java with Files.exists and it returns true.  If I add a Thread.sleep(5000) the view properly displays it.

This behavior makes me think mvc:resources is at least caching which files exist - is it?  Is there a way to tell it to refresh or flush the cache?  Or is there a way to turn it off - this is only for dev.

**Edit to add code example:**

My request handler looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/product/create",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createProduct(Model model) throws Exception {
        return "product/create";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/product/create",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createProduct(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, MultipartFile featuredImage) throws Exception {
        if (!featuredImage.isEmpty()) {
            String featuredImageUrl = "/static/tmp/" + UUID.randomUUID() + featuredImage.getContentType().replace("image/", ".");
            Path featuredImagePath = Paths.get(request.getServletContext().getRealPath(featuredImageUrl));
            Files.createDirectories(featuredImagePath.getParent());
            Files.write(featuredImagePath, featuredImage.getBytes());
            System.out.println("File exists: " + Files.exists(featuredImagePath));

            model.addAttribute("featuredImageUrl", featuredImageUrl);
        }

        return "product/view";
    }
}
```

If I put a Thread.sleep(5000) before the return, the image shows up properly on view.  Files.exists always returns true.

In my dispatcher servlet's xml I have the following to serve the static directory:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
```

The product/view.jsp file basically shows the image if featuredImageUrl isn't null:

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/common/taglibs.jspf" %>
<c:if test="${not empty featuredImageUrl}">
  <img src="<c:url value="${featuredImageUrl}" />" /><br />
</c:if>
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show? Are you loading this static content RESTfull manner?

Comment: I added some sample code that exhibits the problem.